# Cefsharp webbrowser sendkeys

Tags: .net, winforms, cefsharp

i want to input file without open file dialog in cefsharp
like in selenium : 
`Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[accept='*']")).SendKeys(file_name)`

how do we do it with EvaluateScriptAsync in 
 cefsharp ?
`document.querySelector("input[accept='*']") ????`

Comment: For security reasons you cannot use JavaScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571846/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-file-attachment-to-a-webpage-using-cef-winforms

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710646/18452174